# PHP session files not being cleaned up?

Tags: php, session

I have a fairly new site which uses sessions.  I have the following in a file and then require this file on every page which uses session variables :

```
session_name('Login');
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/', '.site.com', false, true);
session_save_path($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../user-sessions');
session_start();
```

As you can see I am using a custom directory to store the sessions one level under the root.  I just realized that none of these session files are being cleaned up.  There is about 150k of them in this folder.

PHP version is 7.2.  What am I missing here?  It was always my understanding these were cleaned up automatically.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's garbage collector won't automatically clean up old session files if the  `session.save_path`-setting has been changed.

As stated in the `php.ini` file right below the setting for `session.gc_maxlifetime`:

```
; NOTE: If you are using the subdirectory option for storing session files
;       (see session.save_path above), then garbage collection does *not*
;       happen automatically.  You will need to do your own garbage
;       collection through a shell script, cron entry, or some other method.
;       For example, the following script would is the equivalent of
;       setting session.gc_maxlifetime to 1440 (1440 seconds = 24 minutes):
;          find /path/to/sessions -cmin +24 -type f | xargs rm
```

The important part being the `If you are using the subdirectory option for storing session files (see session.save_path above), then garbage collection does *not* happen automatically.`

And the description of the `session.save_path`-setting in the `php.ini` states:

```
; Argument passed to save_handler.  In the case of files, this is the path
; where data files are stored. Note: Windows users have to change this
; variable in order to use PHP's session functions.
;
; The path can be defined as:
;
;     session.save_path = "N;/path"
;
; where N is an integer.  Instead of storing all the session files in
; /path, what this will do is use subdirectories N-levels deep, and
; store the session data in those directories.  This is useful if
; your OS has problems with many files in one directory, and is
; a more efficient layout for servers that handle many sessions.
;
; NOTE 1: PHP will not create this directory structure automatically.
;         You can use the script in the ext/session dir for that purpose.
; NOTE 2: See the section on garbage collection below if you choose to
;         use subdirectories for session storage
;
; The file storage module creates files using mode 600 by default.
; You can change that by using
;
;     session.save_path = "N;MODE;/path"
;
; where MODE is the octal representation of the mode. Note that this
; does not overwrite the process's umask.
; http://php.net/session.save-path
;session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/sessions"
```

Here the link to the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/de/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path)

Answer (score 0):

Are you on ubuntu or debian? If so session.gc_probability is typically set to 0 and then they are cleaned up with a cron. Since you are not storing sessions in the default directory they wouldn't get cleaned up with the cron job. You can set session.gc_probability = 1 in php.ini if this is the case or write your own cron script to clean them up. Just make sure you are running cron as user which has appropriate permissions to delete them.

Comment: CentOS actually.